# Titan Graph: dataschema. Where to put state in the graph

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a 'product" vertex that has several relations/edges to 'user' vertices (several possible roles) These roles/edges have state (like so: NON, IN_PROGRESS, DONE). Where best to save these states in the Titan Graph setup? In edge properties? The states are temporary during a sequence of transactions, but they need to be persisted to backend store if user interrupts sequence of transactions or disconnects by network failure or so. (clients that make request come from lossy mobile connections)

So I have my own "states" for my vertices and edges, that have meaning as events and for my log, and I am looking for a best way to save (temporarily) and store (persistently) those states? Anybody that can advise me on the issue (working with a titan graph-dynamoDB setup, now locally, meant to be remote/cloud)? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these states are related to the roles/edges, then they should go into the edge as an edge property. Edge properties can change and you should update these states as they change from non to done.

Comment: Thank you Alaa Mahmoud! This was my guess at first, good to see it confirmed. I am also investigating to use a central vertix for "product' and collect states in there.. like "STATEOFTITLEOFOBJECT" as users are changing these, meaning they add a title for an object they upload, I want to keep state so that when they abandon the task and return to it later is knows where to start. Maybe that is overdoing it...

Comment: Cool! You can always mark the task/edge as 'inactive' for example and keep it part of the graph. This way you can always bring it back later. You can filter it out as you traverse your graph

Comment: Aha! That's a very effective elegant solution. Whenever connection is lost (purposefully, by user or by network failure) all state changes to 'inactive'. After reconnecting we traverse relations for 'inactive' state and get last saved states to continue. Great! Thanks again for yr advice!

Comment: Note that mutating a Titan edge is actually deletion+creation (notice how the edge id will change). When using Cassandra, this can lead to a lot of tombstones if mutating many edges too often. Avoid mutating edges if you can.

Comment: Ok, that is a valid argument to reconsider this route. Not using Cassandra but ES and AWS Dynamo DB for backend index and storage.. What about updating the label of the edge? Does that mutate the edge as well? Or can I just update the label and the edge remains 'as is' intact. As I want a continuous relation in my edge of 'user' to 'product'